# Why Picker label isn't working on ios 16?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, ios16

Label isn't show...is there a workaround rather than adding text on top of it?

```
 Picker(
            selection: $selection,
            content: {
                Text("1").tag("1")
                Text("2").tag("2")
                Text("3").tag("3")
            },
            label: {

                Text("text")
                
            })
```

Trying to fine a way to show label in picker

Comment: This depends heavily on `pickerStyle` and what the parent view is. For some combinations of those, the label is shown. For others, the label is not shown.

Comment: That said, what's wrong with "adding text on top of it"? What counts as "adding text on top of it" and what doesn't?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on `pickerStyle`. If picker style is not defined, it will use `.automatic`, which means how the picker looks will be based on context. For example if we place your picker inside the `List` or `Form` like this:

```
var body: some View {
        List {
            Picker(
                selection: $selection,
                content: {
                    Text("1").tag("1")
                    Text("2").tag("2")
                    Text("3").tag("3")
                },
                label: {

                    Text("text")
                
            })
        }
    }
```

it will show the label:

[image]

Or you can specify the style directly. AFAIK only `pickerStyle(.navigationLink)` will use that label as you expect.